# Можно ли использовать setState вместе с state store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Смысл моего вопроса заключаеться в том, что обязательно ли все данные хранить в store редакса? Можно ли главную информацию к примеру список книг, музыки и т.д. хранить в store, а логику такую как отображение этих данных и крытие в setState, к примеру при клике на кнопку менять булевое значение в соответствии **setState({show: true})** или **setState({show: false})**?

Comment: я бы посмотрел recompose: withState, а также redux-fractal и redux-ui

Answer (score 1):

Не можно, а нужно. Все что касается визуальной составляющий компонента, и данных не выходящих за его рамки(например value для input), хранится в state. А глобальные данные, которые используются в нескольких компонентах, в store редакса. И булевые переменные лучше начинать со слова is..., но это не критично.

Comment: "(например value для input" - а вот redux-form с вами не согласится

Comment: Было бы странно, если бы redux-form работал без redux, вам так не кажется? И, например, react-select со мной полностью согласен. )

Comment: redux-form хранит все значения формы в стейте, что не согласуется с вашим высказыванием, поэтому я привёл примёр

Comment: "(например value для input), хранится в state" и "хранит все значения формы в стейте", я не вижу несогласия, а вы?